# Unable to install spyder in base conda environment

Tags: anaconda, conda, spyder, environment, anaconda3

## *

```

> Unable to install spyder in the base anaconda environment, Below is the error popping while using the conda install spyder in the base environment`your text`*

```
(base) C:\\Users\\Admin\>conda install spyder
Channels:

- defaults
  Platform: win-64
  Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
  Solving environment: \\ warning  libmamba Added empty dependency for problem type SOLVER_RULE_UPDATE
  failed

LibMambaUnsatisfiableError: Encountered problems while solving:

- package spyder-5.2.2-py310haa95532_1 requires spyder-kernels \>=2.2.1,\<2.3.0, but none of the providers can be instad

Could not solve for environment specs
The following packages are incompatible
├─ pin-1 is installable and it requires
│  └─ python 3.10.\* , which can be installed;
├─ spyder is installable with the potential options
│  ├─ spyder 5.2.2 would require
│  │  └─ spyder-kernels \>=2.2.1,\<2.3.0  with the potential options
│  │     ├─ spyder-kernels \[0.2.4|0.2.6|...|2.3.3\] would require
│  │     │  └─ python \>=3.7,\<3.8.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions 
│        └─ spyder-kernels \[2.4.3|2.4.4\], which can be installed;
└─ spyder-kernels 0\*\*  is not installable because there are no viable options
├─ spyder-kernels \[0.2.4|0.2.6|...|2.1.1\], which cannot be installed (as previously explained);
├─ spyder-kernels \[0.2.4|0.2.6|...|2.3.3\], which cannot be installed (as previously explained);
└─ spyder-kernels \[0.5.2|2.1.1|...|2.4.4\], which cannot be installed (as previously explained).

Pins seem to be involved in the conflict. Currently pinned specs:

- python 3.10.\* (labeled as 'pin-1')



Unable to solve the issue
```

Comment: Can you successfully install Spyder in a new conda environment?